# Joining attributes by location/intersect works for all but one polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join, intersect

I used the Join attributes by location and Intersect tools in QGIS 3.4 for my points layer to add a column with name of the intersected area into the attribute table of points. It works perfectly for 5 out of my 6 areas - they are all in one shp with the same characteristics. I tried to export it separately, save it differently, but this one area never works.

Any ideas what could I try?

See printscreen - I selected the result I get after I use the tool and the area for which it doesn't work - the points intersected are not in the result layer.

[image]

Comment: Most likely the geometry of that polygon is faulty.

Comment: There are two core plugins for checking faulty geometry: `Geometry Checker` and `Topology Checker`. (Core plugin means they come pre-installed, but you might need to open the Plugin Manager to enable them.) Both are available through the Vector menu.

Comment: There's also the `Fix Geometries` tool in the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful, didn't know these tools. I managed to find it manually and fix it, all works. Thanks again!